# how do i restrict ip block -range- using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip, block, restrict

This is the IP range I wish to block 61.19.0.0 - 61.19.255.255 
I've google it and found a few information's, but how do you continue the restriction list?

```
    First block /18 starting at 0: 0-63 (64 class C addresses)
    then block /20 starting from there: 64-79 (16 class C addresses)
    then block /22 starting from there: 80-83 (4 class C addresses)
```

what is the next value?

block /22  ? which block covers?

also if i want to ban from

61.0.0.0 - 61.255.255.255 how it's done?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can block it by using:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 61.19
```

or you can use CIDR notation:

```
Deny from 61.19.0.0/16
```

To achieve the secondary goal of blocking all of 61.0.0.0-61.255.255.255, you would modify the above addresses to either:

```
Deny from 61
```

or in CIDR format

```
Deny from 61.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: Additional info: `ORDER` determines in what order the rules are processed. First rule to match is used. If you want to block an arbitrary range, you'll have to look up the CIDR ranges. You can use a tool like [this](http://ping.eu/netmask-calc/) for that. You simply deny access for every range that gives

Comment: thanks for your reply! and for your help! If i want to block 61.61.61.0 to 61.61.61.255 how do i do it?

Comment: @john For `61.61.61.0-255` you want either `Deny From 61.61.61` or `Deny from 61.61.61.0/24`. See any of the many online guides like this for more CIDR numbers: http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It worked and it' great now. Thanks a million!